# Android redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, android-cookiemanager

I'm trying to redirect my user after successful authentication (using AJAX). I've tried using *window.location.href and document.location* but without success. I also want to keep the cookies.

Here's my Android App code:

```
WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.mainView);

myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.100.5:3000/");
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```